# X509Certificate2 prompts me for password

Tags: c#, authentication, httpwebrequest, ssl-certificate, x509certificate2

I have exported my private key to a pfx file and I am using it to post some data to a server. When the code hits this line

```
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2("C:\\mycerts\\dml.pfx","Passw0rd");
```

A prompt comes up and ask me to define a password. I write a new password 2 times. Then when I reach this line

```
Stream newStream = request.GetRequestStream();
```

It prompts me again and I put in the newly defined password and the post is successfull.

Is there a way I can avoid user interaction?

Comment: Hi, in what form are you prompted? I need the same scenario but my code just continues without asking me for the credentials

Comment: Have you been under Local Security Policy as suggested by CryptoGuys answer ?

Comment: The problem was that I wasn't prompted because I was using Local Machine certificates so it didn't impact me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out my certificate had a wicked Crypto service provider. Using certutil -dump I would get this

> ----------------  End Nesting Level 1  ----------------
>
> Provider = CRYPTOMATHiC RSA Full Provider 1.2
>
> Simple container name: Verify
>
> Unique container name: Verify
>
> ERROR: missing key association property: CERT_KEY_IDENTIFIER_PROP_ID
>
> Cannot load key: Key does not exist. 0x8009000d (-2146893811 NTE_NO_KEY)
>
> Encryption test FAILED

Dont know exactly why this is bad but I managed to run a fixing tool and after that it would display

> ----------------  End Nesting Level 1  ----------------
>
> Provider = Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider
>
> Encryption test passed

Now it works without prompting for password

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the system is configured to use private key strong protection for all keys. You should disable this setting by using group policies: http://blogs.technet.com/b/pki/archive/2009/06/17/what-is-a-strong-key-protection-in-windows.aspx

Comment: I went into Local Security Policy and changed the "setting for system cryptography - Force strong key protection for user keys stored on this computer" to User input is not required. But it did not change anything. Could it be that this key on creation has a setting that would overwrite this?

Comment: is your computer a member of Active Directory domain?

Comment: It is not part of that

Comment: did you try another PFX to test? I don't remember right now, but it is unlikely that this setting can be set in PFX file.

Comment: So I found out that a another cryptograhic service provider was installed on this machine. I tried removing this and then there would be no prompt, just an error. I guess my certificates are all connected to this CSP

Comment: I tried just hitting cancel when first being prompted for a new password when running the first line of code. And the the requests goes trough without problems